# Laravel Livewire, not triggering the validation with modals

Tags: php, laravel

i have a laravel livewire 3 application. and i am having this wired issue where i have a Pool Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Pool;

use App\Models\Pool;
use App\Models\PoolLike;
use App\Models\Vote;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class Pools extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var array $pools The pools data.
     */
    public $pools;

    /**
     * The selected option for the pool.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */

    public array $selectedOption = [];


    public function selectOption($poolId, $optionId)
    {
        $this->selectedOption[$poolId] = $optionId;
    }


    /**
     * Vote for a pool option.
     *
     * @param int $poolId The ID of the pool.
     * @return void
     */
    public function vote($poolId)
    {
        if (!isset($this->selectedOption[$poolId])) {
            return;
        }

        $optionId = $this->selectedOption[$poolId];

        Vote::firstOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => auth()->id(), 'pool_id' => $poolId],
            ['option_id' => $optionId]
        );
    }

    public function like($poolId)
    {
        $poolLike = PoolLike::where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('pool_id', $poolId);

        if ($poolLike->exists()) {
            $poolLike->delete();
        } else {
            PoolLike::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'pool_id' => $poolId
            ]);
        }
    }

    #[On('poolCreated')]
    public function render()
    {
        $this->pools = Pool::with(
            [
                'user:id,name,created_at',
                'options',
                'options.votes',
                'likes',
                'votes'
            ]
        )
            ->withCount(['votes', 'likes'])
            ->latest()
            ->get()
            ->each(function ($pool) {
                $pool->options = $pool->getOptionsWithPercentage();
                $pool->user_pools_count = $pool->user->pools()->count();
            });


        return view('livewire.pool.pools', ['pools' => $this->pools]);
    }


    public function openCommentsModal($poolId)
    {
        $this->dispatch('openCommentsModal', poolId: $poolId);
    }
}
```

And the pool blade component

```
<div class="mt-8">
    @foreach ($pools as $pool)
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-4xl mb-6" wire:key="{{ $pool->id }}">
            <div
                class="flex flex-col gap-6 bg-gray-700 text-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 p-8 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                <header class="flex items-center gap-6 w-full pl-0">
                    <img class="w-20 h-20 shadow-lg rounded-lg" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u={{ $pool->user->id }}"
                        alt="avatar">
                    <div class="flex-1">
                        <h1 class="text-lg sm:text-3xl truncate text-white">
                            {{ $pool->user->name }}
                        </h1>
                        <ul class="flex items-center gap-2  stroke-purple-500">
                            <li class="text-xs  font-semibold text-gray-400">
                                {{ $pool->user_pools_count }} {{ Str::plural('Pool', $pool->user_pools_count) }}
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray-400">|</li>
                            <li class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray-400">
                                Member Since
                                {{ $pool->user->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-400">{{ $pool->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
                </header>

                <section class="flex flex-col gap-6">
                    <p class="text-lg text-white tracking-wide">{{ $pool->question }}</p>
                    @foreach ($pool->options as $option)
                        <label>
                            <div class="relative pt-1">
                                <div
                                    class="overflow-hidden h-12 mb-2  flex rounded-full bg-green-50 hover:bg-green-300 {{ $selectedOption == $option->id ? 'bg-green-500 text-white' : '' }} hover:cursor-pointer transition-all">
                                    <div style="width:{{ $option->percentage }}%"
                                        class="shadow-none flex flex-col  justify-center bg-green-400">
                                        <div class="px-4">
                                            <p class="text-lg text-gray-800">
                                                {{ $option->text }}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input @disabled($pool->hasVoted ? true : false)
                                        wire:click="selectOption({{ $pool->id }}, {{ $option->id }})""
                                        type="radio" name="option_id" value="{{ $option->id }}" class="hidden">
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-100">(
                                            {{ $option->votes_count }} {{ Str::plural('vote', $option->votes) }}
                                            ,
                                            {{ $option->percentage }}% )</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    @endforeach
                </section>

                <footer>
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                            <button
                                class="flex items-center gap-2 bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 text-white px-4 py-2 hover:text-red-300 hover:bg-opacity-75 rounded-xl"
                                type="button" @click="$wire.openCommentsModal({{ $pool->id }})">
                                <x-comments-icon />
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" wire:click="like({{ $pool->id }})"
                                class="flex items-center gap-2 bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 text-white px-4 py-2 hover:text-green-400 hover:bg-opacity-75 rounded-xl  {{ $pool->hasLiked ? 'bg-red-300 hover:text-white text-white dark:bg-red-400' : '' }}">
                                <x-like-icon />
                                {{ $pool->likes_count }}
                            </button>
                            <div>
                                <div class="sm:flex items-center hidden  avatar-group -space-x-6">
                                    @foreach ($pool->likes->take(5) as $like)
                                        <div class="avatar">
                                            <div class="w-10">
                                                <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img={{ rand(1, 5) }}" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach

                                    @if ($pool->likes_count - $pool->likes->take(5)->count() !== 0)
                                        <div class="avatar placeholder">
                                            <div class="w-10 bg-neutral text-neutral-content">
                                                <span>+{{ $pool->likes_count - $pool->likes->take(5)->count() }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if (!$pool->hasVoted)
                            <button data-tip="Please select an option to vote!" type="button"
                                wire:click="vote({{ $pool->id }})" @disabled(!isset($selectedOption[$pool->id]) || $selectedOption[$pool->id] == null)
                                class="{{ !isset($selectedOption[$pool->id]) ? 'tooltip' : '' }} bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 text-white px-10 py-4 hover:text-green-300 hover:bg-opacity-75 rounded-xl disabled:hover:text-white disabled:bg-gray-500 disabled:cursor-not-allowed">
                                <x-send-icon />
                            </button>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </footer>

                @livewire('pool.comment', ['poolId' => $pool->id], key($pool->id))
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Also i have a Comment Component, where it displays all the comments also user can add new comment

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Pool;

use App\Models\Comment as CommentModel;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;

class Comment extends Component
{
    public $poolId;

    public $comments;

    public bool $commentsModal = false;

    #[Validate('required|min:3')]
    public string $commentInput = '';


    #[On('openCommentsModal')]
    public function openCommentsModal($poolId)
    {
        $this->commentsModal = true;
        $this->poolId = $poolId;

        $this->comments = CommentModel::withUser()
            ->where('pool_id', $this->poolId)
            ->latest()
            ->get();
    }


    public function addComment()
    {
        $this->validate(); // it's not triggered!

        if (!empty($this->commentInput)) {
            CommentModel::create([
                'pool_id' => $this->poolId,
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'body' => $this->commentInput,
            ]);

            $this->commentInput = '';
            $this->comments = CommentModel::withUser()
                ->where('pool_id', $this->poolId)
                ->latest()
                ->get();
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pool.comment');
    }
}
```

comment blade file

```
<div>
    <x-modal wire:model="commentsModal">
        <div class="flex flex-col max-h-[650px] overflow-y-auto no-scrollbar">
            @if ($comments)
                @foreach ($comments as $comment)
                    <div class="bg-gray-500/10  p-4 my-2 rounded-md shadow-md">
                        <div class="flex items-start justify-between">
                            <div class="flex items-center">
                                <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                                    <img class="w-14 h-14 shadow-lg rounded-lg"
                                        src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u={{ $comment->user->id }}"
                                        alt="{{ $comment->user->name }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-3">
                                    <p class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
                                        {{ $comment->user->name }}
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                        {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                            <p>
                                {{ $comment->body }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-4">
            <div class="w-full mr-3">
                <input wire:model.defer="commentInput" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment .."
                    class="input input-bordered w-full text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400" required />
                @error('commentInput')
                    <div class="text-red-500 text-xs">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <button type="button" wire:click="addComment" class="btn">
                <x-send-icon />
            </button>
        </div>
    </x-modal>
</div>
```

so the issue is here when the user submit i mean click the addComment button the add comment function do not trigger the validation it throw an error if the commentInput is empty

```
Attempted to lazy load [user] on model [App\Models\Comment] but lazy loading is disabled.
```

i am loading the user from the Comment Model

```
    public function scopeWithUser($query)
    {
        return $query->with('user:id,name');
    }
```

Also another weird problem is if i want to track if the commentInput is empty to disable the addComment button livewire do not detect that!

What i am missing?

I tried everything,

Comment: It would be helpful to know which line of code causes the error

Comment: @Pippo i tried to explain the scenario, but it happens when i click the addComment button that calls the method on the Comment that called addComment. The validation do not work. And if you have time this is the repo fully documented
https://github.com/H4ck3r-x0/laravel-text-pool-app and there are factories and seeders.
Thanks

Comment: You can get the line that causes the error from the callstack

Comment: Okey, this is the line and the file
resources/ views/ livewire/ pool/ comment.blade.php 11

                                        src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u={{ $comment->user->id }}"

Comment: Everything seems ok. I suggest you to clear all application caches

Comment: Thanks, but clearing caches do not fix the issue that livewire ignores the adding new comment validation.

Comment: I did a test using your repository and everything works fine. Maybe you introduced some changes in your local copy?

Comment: @Pippo I will see, but did you submit a comment and you got a validation back without any errors?

Comment: Yes, it is so. Try creating a fresh installation in another folder. Maybe it's a package/library issue.